# How to add subheading in product add page-shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

Hi I want to add a sub title in product add page. I am newbie in shopify

[image]

so after title I would like to add subtitle field .I tried it using Metafields & Custom Fields.But is there any option to add without apps?   Any help would be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [metafields](https://shopify.dev/apps/metafields) to create a subtitle field and then integrate the metafield value into the [theme's code](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects/metafield).